# What are the most popular papers on Uber-type spatial matching?

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, matching

This is probably one of those "just google it" kinds of questions, but is there a commonly-accepted "definitive" model in the literature for capturing the kind of matching problem that Uber faces, in (say) a Euclidean sense?  It seems that the significant problem attributes are:

1. Customers arrive in the service region according to a (let's say uniform) spatiotemporal Poisson process.
2. Drivers have a fixed radius of customers that they can visit (ditto for customers).
3. There is a period of time between a customer requesting a ride and getting assigned to a driver, and there is a trade-off:

   a) If the assignment is instantaneous, then you have a greedy assignment policy which could be far from system-optimal.

   b) If the assignment takes a long time, then the assignment is probably quite good, but customers might leave the system due to impatience.

Can anyone suggest some "seminal" papers in this area?  I know it is subjective but am new to the field and trying to "see the forest for the trees".

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to look at the following paper. The authors look at pure online strategies where a decision is made instantly but also look at re-optimization strategies.

> Bertsimas, D., Jaillet, P., & Martin, S. (2019). Online Vehicle
> Routing: The Edge of Optimization in Large-Scale Applications.
> Operations Research, 67(1), 143–162. doi:10.1287/opre.2018.1763